# Reading data from mmaped NULL pointer

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, null, mmap

Check this code:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *addr = mmap(NULL, 6, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(addr, "abcxyz");
    printf("Mapped into addr=0x%X\n", addr);
    printf("%s\n", addr);
    printf("%s\n", NULL);
}
```

`fd` is file descriptor to a file which contain string `abcxyz`
I expected the program should recieve SIGSEGV upon accessing to NULL pointer
But ironically, I got

```
Mapped into addr=0x0
abcxyz
abcxyz
```

What is happened? Why is it possible to map a accessible data to address NULL? With this behavior, how can I use it to exploit the system?

Note that: The program has to run under root privilege.

Note2: The behavior is produced on
`Linux XXXXXX 4.4.0-174-generic #204-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 29 06:41:01 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: "If `addr` is NULL, then the kernel chooses the (page-aligned) address at which to create the mapping" from the docs ( e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html ).

Comment: Try `printf("Mapped into addr = %p\n", (void*)addr);` instead of `printf("Mapped into addr=0x%X\n", addr);` and tell us what is displayed. Using `%X` to display a pointer value is UB.

Comment: Please post all the code including how `fd` has been assigned.

Comment: It's not possible for `printf("%s\n", NULL);` to print `abcxyz`. [Glibc](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c#L1151) prints [`"(null)"`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c#L368). [musl](https://github.com/ifduyue/musl/blob/master/src/stdio/vfprintf.c#L593) does the same. `%X\n", addr);` is undefined behavior and I guess most probably it's only displaying (higher/lower? I think higher, but not sure) 32bits part of the 64bit pointer. Please post an [MCVE]

Comment: @KamilCuk That code doesn't actually call `printf`. GCC optimizes `printf("%s\n", x);` to `puts(x);`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica that's a pretty interesting side effect of optimization, never thought about it! Changing the whole output of the program.

Comment: @KamilCuk I tested, it do print`abcxyz` but replace `NULL` will `0x0` give `(null)` instead.

Answer (score 5):

> What is happened?

Usually, there's no page mapped at `0x0`, so dereferencing a null pointer segfaults. But you explicitly mapped a page there, so it doesn't segfault anymore.

> Why is it possible to map a accessible data to address NULL?

You answered your own question without realizing it:

> Note that: The program has to run under root privilege.

The `vm.mmap_min_addr` sysctl normally prevents this by being set to something above 0. However, that sysctl doesn't apply to processes running as root.

> With this behavior, how can I use it to exploit the system?

You can't, because if you can do that `mmap`, then [you're already on the other side of the airtight hatchway](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060508-22/?p=31283).

By the way, your code is technically Undefined Behavior, since you're still dereferencing NULL even though there is something there. And in fact, with most common libcs, it's only the compiler's optimization of `printf` to `puts` that makes it work at all.

Comment: I see you add MAP_ANONYMOUS and fd = -1. Is it mean that anon file would behave the same?

Comment: @Silver Yes. The effect you're asking about in this question is independent of whether the mapping is file-backed.

Answer (score 2):

> What is happened?

`mmap()` mapped the file you specified at address 0, like you asked.

Obviously, you shouldn't do that (supply `NULL` as the first parameter, with `MAP_FIXED` in flags in the fourth parameter), because then you break all kinds of expectations.

(`MAP_FIXED` is a footgun: when it is not specified, the kernel will honor the address request, *even if already mapped*, steamrolling over any existing mappings.  Only when you do **not** use `MAP_FIXED`, will the kernel make sure the mapping does not overlap existing mappings and so on, avoiding the zero address if at all possible.)

Linux does not try to stop an user from shooting themselves in the foot; it assumes the user knows what they're trying to accomplish, and only ensures privilege separation and so on.  That is why it lets you do things that at first sight do not seem to have any use at all.

(A library might map the first few pages, even as PROT_NONE, and install a SIGBUS handler to catch NULL pointer dereferences without crashing the program.  So, there *are* use cases for this kind of stuff, even if *we* might not think of them.  Conversely, some features can be used in a dangerous/not-useful/self-foot-mutilating manner; the kernel does not judge.)

Also note, as mentioned in comments to the question already, that you are running Linux on an LP64 architecture, where `int` is 32-bit, and `long` and pointers 64-bit.  This means that `%x` or `%X` only prints the low 32 bits of the unsigned integer representation of a value.  Use `%p` for pointers.  For other types, include `<inttypes.h>` (or just `<stdint.h>` for the types without their conversion specifiers), and use specific-width or minimum-width types, like `uint32_t` or `uint_fast32_t`.  At minimum, remember to use `size_t` for in-memory sizes, like string lengths, or array element counts.